# Conditioning of an event related to Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I'm currently reading the book Brownian Motion by Mörters and Peres and on p. 39 the following situation comes up:

We have a Brownian Motion $B(t)$ and two intervals $[a_1,b_1]$ and $[a_2,b_2]$ where $b_1<a_2$. We define $m_1 = \max_{a_1\leq t \leq b_1}B(t)$ and $m_2 = \max_{a_2\leq t \leq b_2}B(t)$. It then follows that $B(a_2)-B(b_1)$, $m_1-B(b_1)$ and $m_2-B(a_2)$ are independent.

**We wan't to show that $\mathbb{P}(m_1 = m_2) = 0$** and therefore they consider the event
$$\{\omega:B(a_2)-B(b_1)= m_1-B(b_1)-(m_2-B(a_2))\}$$

They say that they condition on the values of the random variables $m_1-B(b_1)$ and $m_2-B(a_2)$ and that the output from the LHS is a continuous random variable while the RHS outputs a constant.

**I don't understand what they mean by conditioning in this case.** What I've seen before is conditional expectation and I believe that
$$\mathbb{E}[B(a_2)-B(b_1)\vert m_1-B(b_1)] = \mathbb{E}[B(a_2)-B(b_1)]$$
$$\mathbb{E}[m_1-B(b_1)-(m_2-B(a_2))\vert m_1-B(b_1)] =m_1-B(b_1)$$
holds by the independence however I don't see how this implies the above where they are dealing with a specific event.

Comment: I think they switched the LHS and RHS.  The conditional expectation of the LHS $B(a_2)-B(b_1)$ is constant, whereas RHS just remains the difference of the two random variables.

Comment: Ok thanks, but I don't see how to draw the conclusion from this that the probability of the event where they are equal is 0? Is there some quick way to see this from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $X=B(a_2)-B(b_1)$, $Y=m_1-B(b_1)$,  $Z=m_2-B(a_2)$, and  $m=m_2-m_1=X-Y+Z$. As noted, $X,Y,Z$ are mutually independent. Let $\mu$ be the distribution of $Y$ and $\nu$ the distribution of $Z$. Then, using the independence, because $m=X-Y+Z$,
$$
P[m=0]=\int\int P[X-y+z=0]\mu(dy)\nu(dz).\qquad\qquad (1)
$$
But the random variable $X$ has a continuous distribution, so
$$
P[X=y-z]=0,
$$
for each pair $(y,z)$. It follows that the integral on the right in (1) vanishes, hence so does the left; that is, $P[m=0]=0$.

Comment: Perfect, thanks so it is a consequence of Product measure. I don't understand the conditioning part, is that what you have done?

Comment: Yes. The joint distribution of $X$ and $(Y,Z)$ is a product measure.